# SFML, странная ошибка при попытке добавить загруженную текстуру в std::map

Tags: c++, sfml, текстура

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
std::map<std::string, sf::Texture> textures;
sf::Texture texture;

if (texture.loadFromFile("texture.bmp") == true)
{
    textures.insert({"texture.bmp", texture});
}
```

Я обнаружил странную проблему.

Если приведенный код вызывается до:

```
sf::RenderWindow render_window(...);
```

Тогда в момент вставки в коллекцию я получаю такую ошибку:

```
An internal OpenGL call failed in Texture.cpp(98).

Expression:
    glFlush()
Error description:
    GL_INVALID_OPERATION
    The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.

An internal OpenGL call failed in Texture.cpp(98).
Expression:
   glFlush()
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
   The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.
```

Мои вопросы:

1. Почему это происходит? `SFML` запрещает грузить текстуру до тех пор, пока не создан хотя бы один объект `RenderWindow`?
2. Если да, то где об этом написано?
3. Может ли это быть связано с работой драйверов при наличии двух видеокарт в системе?

Comment: а там написано, что `The maximum size for a texture depends on the graphics driver`, а это неизвестно до создания окна

Comment: @PavelGridin, в обсуждении похожей проблемы на `github` говорится, что текстура может быть загружена до создания и инициализации окна, потому что `SFML` в таком случае использует какой-то предварительный контекст. И текстуру, действительно, можно загружать до создания окна, но вот при копировании происходит ошибка. И об этой проблеме информации я не нашел.

Comment: я просто посмотрел в исходнике Texture.cpp(98), это конструктор Texture и ему imho не хватает размеров, https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp